# Format Double for negative currency, or remove "-" sign from Double

Tags: swift, currency, number-formatting

I have a Double which can be positive or negative that I want to display in the following way:

For positive values:

+$1.10

For negative values:

-$0.50

And blank for 0 values

I've tried like this:

```
Double surcharge = ...
if(surcharge < 0){
    cell.lblSurcharge.text = "-$" + String(format:"%.02f", surcharge)
}else if(surcharge > 0){
    cell.lblSurcharge.text = "+$" + String(format:"%.02f", surcharge)
}else{
    cell.lblSurcharge.text = nil
}
```

but for negative values it shows them like this:

-$-0.50

How can I format it correctly, or remove the "-" from the Double?

Comment: You should be using `NumberFormatter` instead of all of this special code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that `surcharge` is negative at that point, so just add `-` to make it positive for the formatting.  Also, you can move the `"-$"` into the format string:

Change:

```
cell.lblSurcharge.text = "-$" + String(format:"%.02f", surcharge)
```

to:

```
cell.lblSurcharge.text = String(format:"-$%.02f", -surcharge)
```

---

To do it all in one line, use the trinary operator (`?:`) to handle zero and to add the sign to the format string:

```
cell.lblSurcharge.text = surcharge == 0 ? "" : String(format:"%@$%.02f", surcharge > 0 ? "+" : "-", abs(surcharge))
```

Answer (score 11):

As much as possible, you should be making use of the available formatters the API supplies, for example, `NumberFormatter`

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

formatter.string(from: 50.0) // "$50.00"
formatter.string(from: -50.0) // "-$50.00"
```

This makes it easier to support different localisations without any additional code

So, if were to add `formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_UK")`, the output would become...

```
"£50.00"
"-£50.00"
```

Obviously, in most cases I'd use `Locale.current`, but situations change

> Sure, but I want the positive output to show the "+" sign too

It's not as pretty as I might like, but...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.positivePrefix = formatter.plusSign + formatter.currencySymbol

formatter.string(from: 50.0)
formatter.string(from: -50.0)
```

Outputs

```
"+$50.00"
"-$50.00"
```

> such as if the view is reloaded and I don't reset numberStyle to .currency before the String is prepared

Make it lazy property

```
var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.positivePrefix = formatter.plusSign + formatter.currencySymbol
    return formatter
}()
```

And/or a `static` (and possibly lazy) property of "configuration" struct/class

Comment: Sure, but I want the positive output to show the "+" sign too

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Where's there's a will, there's a hack :/

Comment: This seems like the correct way to do it, but I worry I may encounter unexpected results in some rare cases such as if the view is reloaded and I don't reset numberStyle to .currency before the String is prepared.

Comment: The answer I selected is hacky but I feel I can be sure it will work 100% of the time for my specific case where the currency is always "$"

Comment: *"such as if the view is reloaded and I don't reset numberStyle to .currency before the String is prepared"* - Make a `static` lazy property or part of a "configuration" managed property

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer might be to use the "abs" function exposed by the class type.

```
cell.lblSurcharge.text = "-$" + String(format:"%.02f", abs(surcharge))
```